# Arduino JSON foreach loop

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu, json

I'm trying to extract values using ArduinoJson. The values aren't fixed, therefore I need to use the foreach loop.

I'm trying this, but I can't seem to use the values like I could with.

```
root["0"]["value"].as<const char*>();
```

Here is my code.

```
void loop(){
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  if(httpCode > 0) {
    // if Get request has processed
    if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      payload = http.getString();
    }
    if(payload.length() > 0) {
      Serial.println(payload);
      JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(payload);
      if (!root.success()) {
        Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
        jsonBuffer.clear();
      } else {
        Serial.println("Data Fetched");
        for(JsonPair& node : root) {
          Serial.print("0 State: ");
          Serial.println(*node);
        }
        http.end();
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("Payload Empty");
    }
  }
}
```

Please avoid any missing brackets. Thanks in advance.

```
[{"state": true, "value": 10}, {"state": false, "value": 8}, {"state": false, "value": 5}, {"state": false, "value": 13}]
```

Comment: How can we possible answer this question if we don't know what JSON will be fed in and what error occurs?

Comment: wouldn't it be `root[0]["value"]`?

Comment: what does this mean? `avoid any missing brackets` .... how do you avoid something that does not exist?

Comment: @jsotola I meant to say please avoid if I missed some bracket in the code above. Nevermind...

Comment: You should press ctrl-T and indent your code properly, as a start...

Answer (score 2):

I found another way around the solution.

Idk if this is helpful to anyone but the problem was that I had an unknown number of nodes I wanted to loop through, Example of the json format above.

```
void loop(){
int httpCode = http.GET();
  if(httpCode > 0) {
    // if Get request has processed
    if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
          payload = http.getString();
      }
      if(payload.length() > 0){
          JsonArray& nodes = jsonBuffer.parseArray(payload);
          if (!nodes.success()) {
            Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
            jsonBuffer.clear();
          }else{
            int node_length = nodes.size(); 
            for(int i=0; i<node_length;i++){
              Serial.printf("node-%i\nValue : ",i );
              String value = nodes[i]["value"].as<const char*>();
              String state = nodes[i]["state"].as<const char*>();
              Serial.println(value);
              Serial.print("State : ");
              Serial.println(state); 
            }
            http.end();
        }
    }else{
      Serial.println("Payload Empty");
    }
  }

  jsonBuffer.clear();
  delay(8000);
}
```

Comment: so you found out that the json array has a size property?

Comment: Yes both `jsonArray` and `jsonObject` has size property